# redirect to webpage depending on selection in two select drop downs

Tags: javascript

I need a javascript solution for the following situation:

I have two select drop down menus. The combination of the two of them will redirect to either of three websites after clicking the submit button:

```
www.exampledomainI
www.exampledomainII
www.exampledomainIII
```

If "A" selected it always should go straight to www.exampledomainI. No selection of id="number" necessary (select menu id="number" should disappear when selected and vice versa reappear when selection is anything else then "A" in id="letter")

IF the combination (eg A4 or C1 etc) is part of an array within the JavaScript than it should go to www.exampledomainII.

If it is part of a second array than it should go to www.exampledomainIII.

```
<select id="letter">
  <option>A</option>
  <option>B</option>
  <option>C</option>
</select>

<select id="number">
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
  <option>4</option> 
  <option>5</option> 
  <option>6</option> 
</select>  

<input type="submit">
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: Uhm, do you know how you can read the values from a select box and making a redirect to a new location with javascript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the elements in a form, give the options a value attribute, attach an onsubmit listener to the form. If javascript is enabled, do the logic and set *window.location.href* appropriately. If javascript is disabled, not available or fails, have the server do the logic. e.g.

```
<form action="..." onsubmit="return doRedirect(this);">
  <select id="letter">
    <option value="A">A
    <option value="B">B
    <option value="C">C
  </select>

  <select id="number">
    <option value="1">1
    <option value="2">2
    <option value="3">3
  </select>  

  <input type="submit">
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
function doRedirect(form) {
  var letter = form.letter.value;
  var number = form.number.value;

  if ( /* some tests using letter and number */) {
    window.location.href = 'http://whatever.com';
    return false;

  } else if ( /* some other tests using letter and number */) {
    window.location.href = 'http://whatever.com';
    return false;

  } else if ( /* and so on... */) {
    /* whatever */
    return false;
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: nice solution, got it working. We are running the site on php. Could you give me an head start on how this code above would work in php?

Comment: @Christian HTML and Javascript works on client side, php works on server side. If you put this code into a php file, the servlet engine will send it to the browser without any changes.

Answer (score 0):

cannot understand very well your explanation but this may illustrate a little

```
letter_value = document.getElementById('letter').value;
number_value = document.getElementById('number').value;

if (letter_value == 'A') {
  window.location = 'www.exampledomainI';
}
else {
  //cannot understand your explanation for this cases, but just use if else for each case, for example
  if (letter_value == 'B' && (number_value == 1 || number_value == 3)) {
    window.location = 'www.exampledomainII';
  }

  if () {
    ...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here a simple solution for your question

```
    <html>
    <head>
        <script>
            function loadNew()
            {
                selectLetter = document.forms[0].letter.value.toString() + document.forms[0].number.value.toString();
                switch (selectLetter)
                {
                    case "B2", "C1":
                        location.href = "www.exampledomainII.com";
                        break;
                    default:
                        location.href = "www.exampledomainI.com";
                        break;
                }
            }

            function visibilityT()
            {
                if (document.forms[0].letter.value.toString() == "A")
                {
                    document.forms[0].number.style.visibility = "hidden";
                } else {
                    document.forms[0].number.style.visibility = "visible";
                }
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body onLoad="visibilityT()">
        <form onSubmit>
        <select name="letter" id="letter" onChange="visibilityT()">
<option>A</option>
<option selected>B</option>
<option>C</option>
</select>

<select name="number" id="number">
<option>1</option>
<option>2</option>
<option>3</option>
<option>4</option> 
<option>5</option> 
<option>6</option> 
</select>  
            <input type="button" value="submit" onClick="loadNew()">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```